# NSInvalidArgumentException reason: '-[__NSCFString > sortedArrayUsingComparator:]:

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray

I am receiving a weird sort error. I have a list of ranges in an array called wordArrayDuplicates. I need to sort this array based on range location so i convert the string to an NSNumber but it wont compare.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString
>   sortedArrayUsingComparator:]:

```
  - (NSArray *)sortedArray {
            if (!sortedArray) {
            sortedArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
             }
        return [wordArrayDuplicates sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)^(id obj1, id obj2){
            NSNumber * lastName1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSRangeFromString(obj1).location];
            NSNumber * lastName2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSRangeFromString(obj2).location];
            return [lastName1 compare:lastName2]; }];
    }
    -(void)beginGoingThroughDuplicatesAtWordIndex:{
        if (index == 1) {[self loadDuplicates];}
        [string addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName
                       value:(id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor
                       range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
        BOOL shouldContinue = YES;
        while (shouldContinue == YES && index<[[self sortedArray] count]) {
            if (![[tv.text substringWithRange:NSRangeFromString([[self sortedArray] objectAtIndex:index-1])] isEqualToString:[tv.text substringWithRange:NSRangeFromString([[self sortedArray] objectAtIndex:index])]]) {
                shouldContinue = NO;
            }
                [string addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName
                               value:(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor
                               range:NSRangeFromString([sortedArray objectAtIndex:index-1])];
            index++;
        }
           textlayer.string = string;
    }
```

Comment: How do you create and fill `wordArrayDuplicates`? It is definitely not an array and that's the problem.

Comment: thats not the problem because it already works but it just doesn't display them in the correct order. [wordArrayDuplicates addObject:NSStringFromRange([self textPositionToRange:start finish:end])];

Comment: Your error message clearly states that you're calling a `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` on a string object, not an array. So issue is somewhere around it. You may be assigning `wordArrayDuplicated` by mistake somewhere or in other way.

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"%@", wordArrayDuplicates);` right before `return [wordArrayDuplicates sortedArrayUsingComparator:...` and the console will show you what's in that object.  If it's a string (as it seems to be) it will show you what's in the string, which may be a clue as to how it acquires its value.

Comment: [wordArrayDuplicates sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(sortedArrayUsingComparator:)];

Comment: it doesn't even get to the method.

Comment: Where so you call the code `[wordArrayDuplicates sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(sortedArrayUsingComparator:)];`? Post that snippet in your question. It looks like the key to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sort the array using `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`, as in

```
[wordArrayDuplicates sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(sortedArrayUsingComparator:)];
```

you are passing the selector which is going to be called on each of the objects *in the array*. So you must be providing some method that is implemented in the objects that's in the array. For example, `compare:`, a standard method for `NSString`:

```
[wordArrayDuplicates sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

You are passing another `NSArray` method. You must choose, either you want to sort using selector or using comparator, but you cannot call one inside of the other.

---

In your example in `- (NSArray *)sortedArray` you are using `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` correctly, stick to that way.

#### Usage recommendation

In general, one should use `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` when sorting array from one place of the code, to avoid creating selectors in the object classes.

When sorting is being called from many places in the code, then creating a selector may be more useful. Even if it isn't your own object and you're just sorting `NSString` in some special way, you can create a category on `NSString` with some `customCompare:` method and use it.

Comment: which should i use. are the results the same.

Comment: now i get, 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: I've edited the answer for which to use. As for you new issue, you don't provide enough info to figure it out. You seem to be operating on an empty array if you get that error.